# GDAL gdal_polygonize.py TypeError

Tags: python, gdal

I am using GDAL to convert a `.tif` to `.shp` file.

```
gdal_polygonize.py input.tif -f “ESRI Shapefile” out.shp
```

However this does not work and results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 166, in <module>
    drv = ogr.GetDriverByName(format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 5255, in GetDriverByName
    return _ogr.GetDriverByName(*args)
TypeError: in method 'GetDriverByName', argument 1 of type 'char const *'
```

I don't believe there is anything wrong with the `.tif` file or the command

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace “ESRI Shapefile” by 'ESRI Shapefile' or "ESRI Shapefile".
I tried with a random raster and I get no error.

```
gdal_polygonize.py input.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" out.shp
```